# Hide sub menus sometimes

Tags: menus

I have the following css:

```
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}
```

It hides sub-menus for me. It works too well. I'd like the sub-menu to be visible *iff* the parent menu item is the parent of the selected item. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code.

```
.current-menu-ancestor > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

The class current-menu-ancestor appears if the current item is a parent of a current page item.